# Изменение результата нейронной сети

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, keras

Сеть распознает тональность отзыва хороший/плохой. После обучения сети подаю на вход какой-то рандомный отзыв для проверки и результат почему-то изменяется постоянно. Т.е у отзыва  ['best film in the world'] результат сначала может быть 0.8, но после повторной проверки может быть 0,2. НО ведь сеть уже обучена и веса всех слов должны быть постоянные. Сеть:

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Embedding, Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer, text_to_word_sequence
from keras import optimizers

def flatten(iterable, types_to_flatten=(list, tuple)):
    for it in iterable:
        if isinstance(it, types_to_flatten):
            yield from flatten(it)
        else:
            yield it

def get_data(path):
    p = Path(path)
    train = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t', index_col=0)
                       for f in p.glob('train_???.tsv*')],
                      ignore_index=True)
    test = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t', index_col=0)
                      for f in p.glob('test_???.tsv*')],
                      ignore_index=True)
    return ((train['Text'], train['Sentiment']),
           (test['Text'], test['Sentiment']))

# read data
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = get_data(r'D:\download\NLP')

# build vocabulary
t = Tokenizer(num_words=10000)
t.fit_on_texts(X_train)
t.fit_on_texts(X_test)


# build a model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu', input_dim=10000))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(50,activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
optimiz = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy',optimizer = optimiz ,metrics = ['accuracy'])

# convert texts to TF-IDF matrices
X_train = t.texts_to_matrix(X_train, mode='tfidf')
X_test = t.texts_to_matrix(X_test, mode='tfidf')

# fit the model
hist = model.fit(X_train,y_train,validation_data = (X_test,y_test),epochs = 5,batch_size = 64)
```

Тест отзывов:

```
rev=['best film in the world']
t.fit_on_texts(rev
X = t.texts_to_matrix(rev, mode='tfidf'))
model.predict(X)
```

Comment: у меня не получилось это воспроизвести - `model.predict(X)` всегда возвращает одинаковую вероятность

Comment: @MaxU Я делал через юпитер и выполнял несколько раз конкретно этот код `rev=['best film in the world']
t.fit_on_texts(rev
X = t.texts_to_matrix(rev, mode='tfidf'))
model.predict(X)`

Comment: а зачем несколько раз векторизировать один и тот же текст? Попробуйте вызвать несколько раз `model.predict(X)` ...

Comment: @MaxU Здравствуйте, как мне удалить все стоп-слова из текста( находятся в nltk.corpus) и заменить все html теги на пробелы перед тем, как векторизовать текст?

Comment: лучше задайте отдельный вопрос с небольшим примером входных данных и примером того что вы хотите получить